# Can i rotate a column chart inside power app

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have built a canvas inside power app >> and the canvas will show a column chart for a sharepoint list as follow:-

[image]

now is there a way to rotate the column chart and show it as follow:-

[image]

If this is not possible inside power app >> then can i rotate the content using iframe? as i can embed the above chart using iframe..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of now I don't think there's a built in feature to do that. Although, I found a very different and effective approach using gallery [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-create-a-horizontal-column-chart-Tutorial/td-p/149488).